# gitlab plugin test connection issue on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

Im having issue with gitlab plugin test connection on jenkins. it gives error when I hit the "test connection" button with the given values.
GitLab user is maintainer and has full access on it. GitLab API token belongs to this user.

unfortunately it seems no way to track this error. I checked the logs files in jenkins machine as well.

GitLab Plugin Version is -> 1.5.27

[you may see screenshot of the page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd65x.png)

alternative link:

https://gyazo.com/2b81c4310c7a144651fda54c6b1462c1

Comment: Do you see any detailed errors in Jenkins logs?

Comment: unfortunately no. it only says "A Problem Occured while processing the request"

Comment: and also I cannot see any related logs under "jenkins logs" directiory in server